# Composite Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

let $p > 2$ be a prime number.

For each a that belongs to the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, we define the following  polynomial:
 $(x^2 - a)$ 
over the polynomials vector space in $\mathbb{F}_p$ ($p$ polynomials in total).

How many of those polynomials are composite and how many are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard question of [quadratic residues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

The polynomial will be reducible for $(p+1)/2$ values of $a$ (when $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$), irreducible for the remaining $(p-1)/2$ values (when $a$ is not a quadratic residue).

Comment: thanks for your answer , mate

Comment: @idannik, you're welcome.